# Leftjoin based on range in RHS data.frame dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Please consider the following:

I have two `data.frames` each containing (patient) ID's, and per ID the date of assessment. Not all ID's have the same amount of assessments.

`db.x` contains (a small selection of) the ID's an assessment value, and the relative day of the assessment.

`db.y` contains ID's, a response value and its relative assessment time.

**Problem**
For each assessment in `db.x` I need to find the corresponding response within the respective time frame (`min` to `max`) in `db.y`. But since the date of assessment in both `data.frames` do not match (couple of days difference between the assessments) I find this challenging.

Data in both `data.frames` need to be grouped by `ID`.

I would love to have `dplyr` solution but any other would work as well. Please find below my approach, which is obviously not working.

**Approach and data**

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Example data
db.x <- data.frame(id = c(rep(18, 8), rep(19, 3)),
                   value = c(60, 75, 100, 100, 85, 80, 80, 90,
                             90, 80, 100),
                   time = c(-8, 85, 203, 259, 441, 623, 791, 938,
                            -7, 85, 169))

# View data
db.x
#>    id value time
#> 1  18    60   -8
#> 2  18    75   85
#> 3  18   100  203
#> 4  18   100  259
#> 5  18    85  441
#> 6  18    80  623
#> 7  18    80  791
#> 8  18    90  938
#> 9  19    90   -7
#> 10 19    80   85
#> 11 19   100  169

db.y <- data.frame(id = c(rep(18, 5), rep(19, 4)),
                   response = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "c",
                                "b", "b", "b", "b"),
                   time = c(78, 196, 251, 342, 454,
                            79, 189, 281, 303))

# View data
db.y
#>   id response time
#> 1 18        a   78
#> 2 18        a  196
#> 3 18        a  251
#> 4 18        b  342
#> 5 18        c  454
#> 6 19        b   79
#> 7 19        b  189
#> 8 19        b  281
#> 9 19        b  303

# Extract the min and max time of the response
db.y <- db.y %>%
        group_by(id, response) %>%
        mutate(min = min(time), max = max(time)) %>%
        distinct(id, response, min, max) %>% 
        ungroup

db.y
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>      id response   min   max
#>   <dbl> <fct>    <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1    18 a           78   251
#> 2    18 b          342   342
#> 3    18 c          454   454
#> 4    19 b           79   303

# PROBLEM: How can I match the responses in db.x to the min/max times in db.y?
db.x %>%
        group_by(id) %>%
        mutate(response = ifelse(time %in% db.y %>% group_by(id = id) %>% select(min, max),
                                 response, NA))
#> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots): Evaluation error: no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "logical".

# Desired output
db.x %>% 
        mutate(response = c(NA, "a", "a", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "b", "b"))
#>    id value time response
#> 1  18    60   -8     <NA>
#> 2  18    75   85        a
#> 3  18   100  203        a
#> 4  18   100  259     <NA>
#> 5  18    85  441     <NA>
#> 6  18    80  623     <NA>
#> 7  18    80  791     <NA>
#> 8  18    90  938     <NA>
#> 9  19    90   -7     <NA>
#> 10 19    80   85        b
#> 11 19   100  169        b
```

<sup>Created on 2018-11-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go for a `full_join` if you would like to stay within `tidyverse` framework (which otherwise does not support `non-equi` joins):

```
library(dplyr)

db.x %>%
  full_join(db.y) %>%
  mutate(
    response = if_else(time >= min & time <= max, as.character(response), NA_character_)
  ) %>% distinct(id, value, time, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
  select(-min, -max)
```

Output:

```
   id value time response
1  18    60   -8     <NA>
2  18    75   85        a
3  18   100  203        a
4  18   100  259     <NA>
5  18    85  441     <NA>
6  18    80  623     <NA>
7  18    80  791     <NA>
8  18    90  938     <NA>
9  19    90   -7     <NA>
10 19    80   85        b
11 19   100  169        b
```

However, this is much more straightforward and scalable in `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(db.y)[setDT(db.x), on = .(id = id, min <= time, max >= time), .(id, value, time, response)]
```

Output:

```
    id value time response
 1: 18    60   -8     <NA>
 2: 18    75   85        a
 3: 18   100  203        a
 4: 18   100  259     <NA>
 5: 18    85  441     <NA>
 6: 18    80  623     <NA>
 7: 18    80  791     <NA>
 8: 18    90  938     <NA>
 9: 19    90   -7     <NA>
10: 19    80   85        b
11: 19   100  169        b
```

Comparison in terms of speed:

```
Unit: milliseconds
       expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
 tidyverser 5.703497 6.369896 7.400882 7.033012 8.043276 12.162548   100
         dt 1.812313 2.088171 2.506833 2.485092 2.958956  3.384321   100
```